# Check Application Settings' scope programmatically

Tags: c#, .net, application-settings

How can I get the list of **UserScoped** Settings in windows application?
So far I have got the list of all Settings using this code:

```
var SettingItems = Properties.Settings.Default.Properties;
foreach (SettingProperty prop in SettingItems)
{
    var attribs = prop.Attributes;
    //HERE I WANT TO CHECK THE SCOPE OF THE SETTING ITEM ...
}
```

and I know that there is an attribute that contains the scope of setting item name **UserScopedSettingAttribute**, the problem is that I can not get that property to check and filter the user scoped items (and not the application scoped ones)

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

```
bool IsUserSetting = (from attr in prop.Attributes
                          where (attr.value) is System.Configuration.UserScopedSettingAttribute
                          select attr).Any;
```

Comment: Not sure if it works with other .NET versions but I have a compilation error (CS1934) with `prop.Attributes` in your code. My WinForms project is in .NET Framework 4.7.2.

Comment: You should add explanation.

Answer (score 0):

The following method can be used to check if a setting is user-scoped:

```
private bool IsUserScopedSetting(SettingsProperty prop)
{
    foreach (object att in prop.Attributes.Values)
    {
        if (att is UserScopedSettingAttribute)
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

To use the method, add the following lines after the `// HERE I WANT TO CHECK THE SCOPE OF THE SETTING ITEM ...` line:

```
if (IsUserScopedSetting(prop))
{
    MessageBox.Show($"'{prop.Name}' is a user setting.");
}
```

If your project settings are defined as follows then this code will show a `MessageBox` saying *'UserSetting1' is a user setting*:

[image]